# How to interpolate a variable in IconData in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, font-awesome

I want to show the icon of a social media.

```
String socialMedia = 'facebook';
```

Then in my build function I want to use this variable in my Icon widget

```
Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.socialMedia)
```

How can I interpolate this variable? Is it possible?
It would become easy for me if I could use the variable like this. Because now I can use the variable to change the icon accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/icons_helper 
You can use `getIconUsingPrefix` and for `FontAwesome` Icon you can prefix string with `fa.`

code snippet

```
Icon(getIconUsingPrefix(name: 'fa.fiveHundredPx'),
                color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor, size: 128.0),
Icon(getIconUsingPrefix(name: 'fa.facebook'),
    color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor, size: 128.0),
Icon(getIconUsingPrefix(name: 'add'),
    color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor, size: 128.0),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:icons_helper/icons_helper.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(       
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,       
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {     
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(       
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(        
        child: Column(          
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(getIconUsingPrefix(name: 'fa.fiveHundredPx'),
                color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor, size: 128.0),
            Icon(getIconUsingPrefix(name: 'fa.facebook'),
                color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor, size: 128.0),
            Icon(getIconUsingPrefix(name: 'add'),
                color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor, size: 128.0),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot...I did a workaround and put all my icons in a list and loop through each of them and compared it to my string and then returned the needed Icondata. This looks much better and less resource intensive..thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The library suggested in the accepted answer is no longer supported and is Dart3 incompatible.

The [latest font_awsome_flutter documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/font_awesome_flutter/latest/) includes the solution and explains the limitations

> ...Probably the
> most requested feature after support for pro icons is the ability to
> retrieve an icon by their name. This was previously not possible,
> because a mapping from name to icon would break all discussed
> optimizations. Please bear in mind that this is still the case. As all
> icons could theoretically be requested, none can be removed by
> flutter. It is strongly advised to only use this option in conjunction
> with a limited set of styles and with as few of them as possible...